# Loading JSON into timemap

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I want to load a JSON into a timemap, and my code seems to be missing something to configure the JSON correctly. JSON format below

> {"results": [{"Lat": "34.0453113", "text": "Historic Core DTLA",
>   "Lon": "-118.2501836", "bicyclistCount": "26", "date": "2014-10-15"},
>   {"Lat": "34.0444899", "text": "Spring @ 7", "Lon": "-118.2523059",
>   "bicyclistCount": "16", "date": "2014-10-26"}]}

This [link](http://bicyclistscount.net/examples/BicyclistsCount_timemap.html) contains the html file based mainly on a timemap [example](http://timemap.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0.1/examples/pathlines.html). It opens up the timeline and map, but the data does not load. Also the map won't zoom in and out, though I want to solve the JSON load issue first. Do you have a suggestion on what I can change? Adding the JavaScript code below. Thanks, Patty

The JavaScript code:

```
var tm;
var errFn = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  alert(textStatus);
  }

$(function() {

tm = TimeMap.init({
    mapId: "map",               // Id of map div element (required)
    timelineId: "timeline",     // Id of timeline div element (required) 
    options: {
        eventIconPath: "../images/"
    },
    datasets: [
        {
            title: "JSON String Dataset",
            type: "json",

            options: {
                // json file
                url: "output.json", <!--this file sits in the same folder as the HTML-->
                error: errFn,
            }
        }
    ], 

  bandIntervals: [
         Timeline.DateTime.DAY, 
         Timeline.DateTime.WEEK
     ]
  });

    <!--start loading data-->
        function transformData(data) {      
      var text, Lat, Lon, bicyclistCount, date; <!--is this how the data is called?-->

    var newData = {
    "title" : text,
    "start" : date,

    "options" : {
        "description" : bicyclistCount
    }
};
newData["point"] = { 
   "lat" : Lat,
    "lon" : Lon,
};            
}
});
<!--end loading data-->
```

Comment: did you check error log console

Comment: I see a javascript error on your page: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on this line: `data.forEach(function(item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change json then define custom loader and configure Timemap to use it.

```
$(function() {

TimeMap.loaders.custom = function(options) {
    var loader = new TimeMap.loaders.remote(options);
    loader.parse = JSON.parse;
    loader.preload = function(data) {
        return data["results"]
    }
    loader.transform = function(data) {
        return {
            "title" : data.text,
             "start" : data.date,
            "options" : {
            "description" : data.bicyclistCount
        },
        "point": { 
            "lat" : data.Lat,
            "lon" : data.Lon,
            }
        };
    };
    return loader;
};

tm = TimeMap.init({
    mapId: "map",               // Id of map div element (required)
    timelineId: "timeline",     // Id of timeline div element (required) 
    options: {
        eventIconPath: "../images/"
    },
    datasets: [
        {
            title: "JSON String Dataset",
            type: "custom",

            options: {
                // json file
                url: "output.json"
            }
        }
    ], 

 bandIntervals: [
        Timeline.DateTime.DAY, 
        Timeline.DateTime.WEEK
    ]
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't mentioned it, but it is better if changing the JSON is not necessary. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

I see a javascript error on your page: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on this line: `data.forEach(function(item)`

data is an Object, not an Array

```
Object
results: Array[10]
```

Change your JSON from:

```
{"results": [{"Lat": "34.0453113", "text": "Historic Core DTLA", "Lon": "-118.2501836", "bicyclistCount": "26", "date": "2014-10-15"}, {"Lat": "34.0444899", "text": "Spring @ 7", "Lon": "-118.2523059", "bicyclistCount": "16", "date": "2014-10-26"}]}
```

To:

```
[{"Lat": "34.0453113", "text": "Historic Core DTLA", "Lon": "-118.2501836", "bicyclistCount": "26", "date": "2014-10-15"}, {"Lat": "34.0444899", "text": "Spring @ 7", "Lon": "-118.2523059", "bicyclistCount": "16", "date": "2014-10-26"}]
```

(make it an array not an object with an array as its "results" property)

Answer (score -1):

Change your JSON Format to:

```
[
  {
    "title":"example",
    "start":"1968-10-12",
    "end": "1968-11-12",
  }

]
```