# how to specify my Longitude and latitude for use in a timemap

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, timeline.js

I'm having trouble figuring out how to specify my Longitude and latitude for use in a timemap. This is my JSON:

**[{"lon":"106.78185","title":"ZAKI","start":"2016-05-25","description":"OPERATION","Id":1,"lat":-6.2206087,"timeStart":"18:00:00"}]**

And below is the HTML file I'm working with.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>TESTER</title>   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&sensor=false"></script>    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/mxn/mxn.js?(googlev3)"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/timeline-2.3.0.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/timeline-1.2.js"></script>  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/timemap.js"></script>  <script type="text/javascript" src="timemap_full.pack.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript" src="src/loaders/json.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="src/loaders/progressive.js" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tm;
            var errFn = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(textStatus);
            }
            $(function() {

                TimeMap.loaders.custom = function(options) {
                    var loader = new TimeMap.loaders.remote(options);
                    loader.parse = JSON.parse;
                    loader.preload = function(data) {
                        return data["rows"]
                    }
                    loader.transform = function(data) {
                        return {
                            "title" : data.title,
                            "start" : data.date,
                            "options" : {
                                "description" : data.description
                            },
                            "point": {
                                "lat" : data.Lat,
                                "lon" : data.Lon
                            }
                        };
                    };
                    return loader;
                };

                //    <!--start loading data-->
                tm = TimeMap.init({
                    mapId: "map",               // Id of map div element (required)
                    timelineId:"timeline",     // Id of timeline div element (required) 
                    options: {
                        eventIconPath: "/TimeMaps/images/"
                    },
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            title: "Tacking OPS",
                            type: "json",
                            options: {
                                // json file
                                method:'GET',
                                url: "getDataTracking",
                                error: errFn
                            }
                        }
                    ], 

                    bandIntervals: [
                        //                        Timeline.DateTime.DAY, 
                        //                        Timeline.DateTime.WEEK
                        Timeline.DateTime.DAY,                         
                        Timeline.DateTime.MONTH
                    ]
                });
            });   

        </script>

        <link href="css/examples.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="help">
            <h1>TIME MAPS CSA</h1>
           </div>
        <div id="timemap">
            <div id="timelinecontainer">
                <div id="timeline"></div>
            </div>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>TESTER</title> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/mxn/mxn.js?(googlev3)"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/timeline-2.3.0.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/timeline-1.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/timemap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="timemap_full.pack.js"></script>  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/loaders/json.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/loaders/progressive.js" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tm;
            var errFn = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(textStatus);
            }
            $(function() {

                TimeMap.loaders.custom = function(options) {
                    var loader = new TimeMap.loaders.remote(options);
                    loader.parse = JSON.parse;
                    loader.preload = function(data) {
                        return data["rows"]
                    }
                    loader.transform = function(data) {
                        return {
                            "title" : data.title,
                            "start" : data.date,
                            "options" : {
                                "description" : data.description
                            },
                            "point": {
                                "lat" : data.Lat,
                                "lon" : data.Lon
                            }
                        };
                    };
                    return loader;
                };

                //    <!--start loading data-->
                tm = TimeMap.init({
                    mapId: "map",               // Id of map div element (required)
                    timelineId:"timeline",     // Id of timeline div element (required) 
                    options: {
                        eventIconPath: "/TimeMaps/images/"
                    },
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            title: "Tacking OPS",
                            type: "json",
                            options: {
                                // json file
                                method:'GET',
                                url: "getDataTracking",
                                error: errFn
                            }
                        }
                    ], 

                    bandIntervals: [
                        //                        Timeline.DateTime.DAY, 
                        //                        Timeline.DateTime.WEEK
                        Timeline.DateTime.DAY,                         
                        Timeline.DateTime.MONTH
                    ]
                });
            });   

        </script>

        <link href="css/examples.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="help">
            <h1>TIME MAPS CSA</h1>
           </div>
        <div id="timemap">
            <div id="timelinecontainer">
                <div id="timeline"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="mapcontainer">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body> </html>
            <div id="mapcontainer">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>  </html>
```

this my servlet code

```java
for (int i = 0; i < listDataTracking.size(); i++) {
                org.json.simple.JSONObject obj = new org.json.simple.JSONObject();
                EntityTracking dataTracking = listDataTracking.get(i);

                if (dataTracking.getIdTracking() == null) {
                    obj.put("Id", "");
                } else {
                    obj.put("Id", dataTracking.getIdTracking());
//                    writer.print(dataTracking.getIdTracking());
                }
                if (dataTracking.getTglSend() == null) {
                    obj.put("start", "");//tanggal
                } else {
                    obj.put("start", sdf.format(dataTracking.getTglSend()));
//                    writer.print(sdf.format(dataTracking.getTglSend()));
                }
                if (dataTracking.getJamSend() == null) {
                    obj.put("jamstart", "");
                } else {
                    obj.put("jamstart", dataTracking.getJamSend());
//                    writer.print(dataTracking.getJamSend());
                }
                if (dataTracking.getUser_name().getUserName() == null) {
                    obj.put("title", "");
                } else {
                    obj.put("title", dataTracking.getUser_name().getUserName().toUpperCase());
//                    writer.print(dataTracking.getUser_name().getUserName());
                }
                if (dataTracking.getUser_name().getRoleName() == null) {
                    obj.put("description", "");
                } else {
                    obj.put("description", dataTracking.getUser_name().getRoleName().toUpperCase());
//                    writer.print(dataTracking.getUser_name().getUserName());
                }
                if (dataTracking.getGetLatitude() == null) {
                    obj.put("lat", "");
                } else {
//                    
                    obj.put("lat", dataTracking.getGetLatitude());
                }
                if (dataTracking.getGetLongitude() == null) {
                    obj.put("lon", "");
                } else {
//                    
                    obj.put("lon", dataTracking.getGetLongitude());
                }

                arrayObj.add(obj);
            }
```

My new HTML file

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>-->
        <title>~:. TimeMaps .:~</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/csalogo.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

        <!--       
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
        -->

        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBTquZF3N7wt_qze9l02cX8MSAkUEvBpuE&sensor=false"></script>-->

        <!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>-->

        <!--        
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/mxn/mxn.js?(googlev3)"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/timeline-1.2.js"></script>
        <script src="src/timemap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="src/timemap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="src/loaders/json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="src/loaders/progressive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--        <script src="src/ext/circle_icons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
        <!-- source 
        http://www.vermontelectric.coop/custom/timemap/docs/symbols/TimeMap.loaders.json.html
        http://www.ibiblio.org/tamil/maps/docs/symbols/TimeMap.loaders.jsonp.html#constructor
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683375/loading-json-into-timemap
        https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/timemap-development/MNjFbvMY42w
        http://www.gps-coordinates.net/
        http://en.marnoto.com/2014/04/converter-coordenadas-gps.html
        https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/#basics
        http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/10/05/converting-decimal-degrees-to-degreesminutesseconds-astronomy-with-your-personal-computer.aspx
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each
        http://jsfiddle.net/5pjha/
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tm;
            var isi_url ="getDataTrackingServlet";
            var isi_jon, lon,lat,title,start,jamstart,description,theme;
            var errFn = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(textStatus);
            }
            //            $(function() {
            $(function() {

                $.getJSON(isi_url, function (json) {

                    $.each(json.results, function(i, item) {

                        lat = item.lat;
                        lon = item.lon;
                        title = item.title;   
                        start = item.start;         
                        description = item.description;  
                        jamstart = item.jamstart;  
                        theme = item.theme;  

                        //                    })
                        console.log('Latitude : ',i, lat);
                        console.log('Longitude : ',i, lon);
                        console.log('title : ',i, title);
                        console.log('start : ',i, start);
                        console.log('description : ',i, description);
                        console.log('jamstart : ',i, jamstart); 
                        console.log('theme : ',i, theme); 

                        tm = TimeMap.init({

                            mapId: "map",               // Id of map div element (required)
                            timelineId:"timeline",     // Id of timeline div element (required) 
                            options: {
                                mapType: "physical",
                                eventIconPath: "/TimeMaps/images/"

                            },

                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    //                                    id:"trackingOPs",
                                    title: "Tacking OPS",
                                    //type:"basic","json"
                                    type: "basic",
                                    options: {
                                        //                                method:'GET',
                                        //                                url: isi_url,
                                        //                                "theme": "Red",                                        
                                        //                                error: errFn,
                                        items: [

                                            {
                                                "start" : item.start,
                                                "end" : item.jamstart,
                                                "point" : {
                                                    "lat" : item.lat,
                                                    "lon" : item.lon
                                                },
                                                "title" : item.title,
                                                "options" : {
                                                    // set the full HTML for the info window
                                                    "infoHtml": "<div class='custominfostyle'><b>"+item.title+"<br/>"+"Divisi :"+" "+item.description+"<br/>"+"Postition :"+item.lat+","+item.lon+
                                                        "</b></div>",
                                                    "theme": item.theme
                                                }

                                            }],events: {
                                            click: function(marker, event, context){
                                                markerSelected(context.id);
                                            }
                                            //                                items: [
                                            //                                    {
                                            //                                        "start" :"2016-05-27",
                                            //                                        "end" : "2016-05-27",
                                            //                                        "point" : {
                                            //                                            "lat" : -6.2206089,
                                            //                                            "lon" : 106.7810652
                                            //                                        },
                                            //                                        "title" : "ZAKI",
                                            //                                        "options" : {
                                            //                                            // set the full HTML for the info window
                                            //                                            "infoHtml": "<div class='custominfostyle'><b>Domenico Ghirlandaio</b> was a visual artist of some sort.</div>"
                                            //                                        }
                                            //                                    }]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],                      
                            //                        bandIntervals: [
                            //                            //                        Timeline.DateTime.DAY, 
                            //                            //                        Timeline.DateTime.WEEK
                            //                            Timeline.DateTime.DAY,  
                            //                            Timeline.DateTime.MONTH
                            //                        ]
                            //                        bandInfo: [
                            //                            {
                            //                                width:          "85%", 
                            //                                intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.DAY, 
                            //                                intervalPixels: 210
                            //                            },
                            //                            {
                            //                                width:          "15%", 
                            //                                intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.MONTH, 
                            //                                intervalPixels: 150,
                            //                                showEventText:  false,
                            //                                trackHeight:    0.2,
                            //                                trackGap:       0.2
                            //                            }
                            //                        ]
                            bandIntervals: "wk"
                        });

                        // filter function for tags
                        var hasSelectedTag = function(item) {
                            console.log(item.opts.tags.indexOf(window.selectedTag));
                            // if no tag was selected, everything passes
                            return !window.selectedTag || (
                            // item has tags?
                            item.opts.tags && 
                                // tag found? (note - will work in IE; Timemap extends the Array prototype if necessary)
                            item.opts.tags.indexOf(window.selectedTag) >= 0
                        );
                        };

                        // add our new function to the map and timeline filters
                        tm.addFilter("map", hasSelectedTag); // hide map markers on fail
                        tm.addFilter("timeline", hasSelectedTag); // hide timeline events on fail

                        // onChange handler for pulldown menu
                        $('#tag_select').change(function() {
                            window.selectedTag = $(this).val();
                            // run filters
                            tm.filter('map');
                            tm.filter('timeline');
                        });

                    });
                });               
            });   
            //<!--end loading data-->


        </script>

        <link href="css/examples.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <style>
            div#timelinecontainer{ height: 310px; }
            div#mapcontainer{ height: 300px; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="help">

        </div>
        <div id="timemap">
            <div id="timelinecontainer">
                <div id="timeline"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="mapcontainer">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

new My json Data

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "lon":"106.7810652",
         "title":"ZAKI",
         "start":"2016-06-01",
         "description":"OPERASIONAL",
         "theme":"red",
         "Id":1,
         "lat":"-6.2206089",
         "jamstart":"18:00:00"
      },
      {
         "lon":"106.7822585",
         "title":"ARDYAN",
         "start":"2016-06-01",
         "description":"OPERASIONAL",
         "theme":"orange",
         "Id":2,
         "lat":"-6.2216851",
         "jamstart":"18:00:00"
      }
   ]
}
```

new output Image
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkH0A.png)
[TimeMaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtStE.png)
Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks,

Comment: One problem you might have. You specify the longitude as a string: `"lon":"106.78185"`  But the latitude you don't: `"lat":-6.2206087`

Comment: I specify my lon and lat as a String, but its doesn't work

Comment: The other problem you might have. Javascript is case-sensitive.  You specify `lat` and `lon` in your JSON, but you refer to these as `data.Lat` and `data.Lon`.  Try `data.lat` and `data.lon`.  Also what do you get if you do `console.log(data)` inside your transform function?

Comment: @duncan, I've got problem to showing 2 data at my apps.